# Update has no effect on scores (Prediction API)

Tags: ruby, google-prediction

I'm experimenting with the `language_id.txt` dataset from the Google Prediction example. Right now I'm trying to update the model with the following method:

```
def update(label, data)
  input = @prediction.trainedmodels.update.request_schema.new
  input.label = label
  input.csv_instance = [data]
  result = @client.execute(
    :api_method => @prediction.trainedmodels.update,
    :parameters => {'id' => MODEL_ID},
    :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'},
    :body_object => input
  )
  assemble_json_body(result)
end
```

(This method is based on some [Google sample code](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/source/browse/prediction/prediction.rb?repo=samples).)

My problem is that these updates have no effect. Here are the scores for `This is a test sentence.` regardless of how many updates I run:

```
{
   "response":{
      "kind":"prediction#output",
      "id":"mymodel",
      "selfLink":"https://www.googleapis.com/prediction/v1.5/trainedmodels/mymodel/predict",
      "outputLabel":"English",
      "outputMulti":[
         {
            "label":"English",
            "score":0.420937
         },
         {
            "label":"French",
            "score":0.273789
         },
         {
            "label":"Spanish",
            "score":0.305274
         }
      ]
   },
   "status":"success"
}
```

Per the disclaimer at the bottom of "[Creating a Sentiment Analysis Model](https://developers.google.com/prediction/docs/sentiment_analysis)", I have made sure to update at least 100 times before expecting any changes. First, I tried using a single sentence and updating it 1000 times. Second, I tried using ~150 unique sentences drawn from Simple Wikipedia and updated with each once. Each update was "successful":

```
{"response":{"kind":"prediction#training","id":"mymodel","selfLink":"https://www.googleapis.com/prediction/v1.5/trainedmodels/mymodel"},"status":"success"}
```

but neither approach changed my results.

I've also tried using the APIs Explorer (Prediction, v1.5) and updating ~300 times that way. There's still no difference in my results. Those updates were also "successful".

```
200 OK
{
"kind": "prediction#training",
"id": "mymodel",
"selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/prediction/v1.5/trainedmodels/mymodel"
}
```

I am quite sure that the model is receiving these updates. `get` and `analyze` both show that the model has `numberInstances": "2024"`. Oddly, though, `list` shows that the model has `"numberInstances": "406"`.

At this point, I don't know what could be causing this issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not necessary, or even standard, to put headers like "**Background**", "**Problem**", etc., in your question. Instead, write it clearly and they won't be needed. In general, format your question like the majority of others and you'll do well.

Comment: found the answer to your problem? having same problem

Comment: Mind answering your own question with the solution? http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: FYI, since April 2018 the Cloud Prediction API was shut down. That serve has been replaced by Cloud Machine Learning Engine, https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/.

Comment: Perhaps asking for the obvious case, but what is the value of `MODEL_ID` in your first code snippet? Are you sure that your retrieving the (updated) predictions from the same model you're updating?

Answer (score 1):

2019 Update

Based on the comment from Jochem Schulenklopper that the API was shut down in April 2018.

> Developers who choose to move to the Google Cloud Machine Learning Engine will have to recreate their existing Prediction API models.

Machine Learning API examples: 
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples